# Plupload integration in custom form

Tags: 7, forms, files

I have been trying to use plupload field in a custom form which I am doing by using the following code:

```
  $form['picture_upload'] = array(
    '#type' => 'plupload',
    '#title' => t(''),
    '#size' => 50,
    '#description' => t(''),
    '#upload_validators' => array(
      'file_validate_extensions' => array('jpg jpeg gif png'),
    ),
  );
```

This works fine but when I add files it shows the list of files rather than thumbnails like in this [example](http://www.plupload.com/examples/ui).

What changes do I need to make in order for the widget to show thumbnails rather than a list?